# Считать qr code из браузера телефона

Tags: javascript, reactjs, qrcode

Мне необходимо считать qr code c web страницы с телефона на Android, для этого решил написать страницу используя ReactJS, нашел библиотеку react-qr-reader, взял код из примера в документации
В браузере Chrome на компе все работает (когда подключена web камера), при открытии страницы на устройстве на android, вижу следующее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если открыть консоль

> message: "No video input devices found"
>
> name: "NoVideoInputDevicesError"

Comment: Для локальных ресурсов нельзя получить доступ к устройствам записи звука и видео (соображения безопасности). У Вас IP host 192.168.* - браузер не будет просить доступа для него к камерам.

Comment: https необходимо настроить?

Comment: Сделать "удалённый хост". Можете схитрить, и на DNS прописать локальный адрес... Типа testnig.example.com A 192.168.0.155, у меня в своё время прокатывало :)

Comment: Или там где то в недрах браузера какую то галочку снять можно вроде.. Давно было, не помню уже :)

Comment: благодарю, буду пробовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из соображений безопасности, браузер не запрашивал доступ к устройствам записи звука и видео так как был не защищенный протокол http, когда установил https, все заработало.

Для этого необходимо в `package.json` прописать:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start",
```